# Is there a standard notation for a function's domain, codomain, and graph?

Tags: functions, notation

If I have a given function $f$, is there a standard notation for $f$'s domain, codomain and graph? One that I can use even if $f$ was not explicitly defined?

The definition of a function, as I was taught, is an ordered 3-tuple $\left(A,B,G\right) $ where $A$ is the domain, $B$ is the co-domain, and $G$ is the graph.

For example if I have the function $f=\left(A,B,G\right)=\left(\left\{ 1,2,3\right\} ,\left\{ 4,5,6\right\} ,\left\{ \left(1,4\right),\left(2,5\right),\left(3,4\right)\right\} \right)$

Meaning $\begin{cases}
f\left(1\right)=4\\
f\left(2\right)=5\\
f\left(3\right)=4
\end{cases}$

Is there a standard notation similar to this?:

$Domain(f)=\left\{ 1,2,3\right\}$

$Codomain(f)=\left\{ 4, 5, 6\right\}$

$Graph(f)=\left\{ \left(1,4\right),\left(2,5\right),\left(3,4\right)\right\}$

The closest notation I can think of is for $f$'s *image*: $f[A]$, and using this, $f$'s domain can be (somewhat convolutedly) written as $f^{-1}[f[A]]$. Both of these notations require $A$ to be explicitly named/defined, which is disadvantageous.

Comment: But as $f$ is not injective, $f^{-1}$ is not well-defined, so you can't write $f^{-1}(f(A))$.

Comment: @Henrik Since $A$ is a set, the convention is to interpret $f(A)$ as the image of $A$ under $f$, and $f^{-1}(f(A))$ as the preimage of $f(A)$.

Comment: @Toldry $\operatorname{dom}(f)$ and $\operatorname{ran}(f)$ are common notations for the domain and range; I have also seen simply $D(f)$ and $R(f)$, though this is probably bad notation, as $D$ could be confused with a differential operator.  $\operatorname{codom}(f)$ can be used for the codomain.  $\Gamma(f)$ is common notation for the graph.

Comment: @Henrik I use the notation $f^{-1}[A]$ with square brackets to denote the preimage of a group, as explicitly differentiated from the notation $f^{-1}(1)$ with parentheses, which is the preimage of a single element

Comment: I've seen Dmn$(f)$ and Rng$(f)$ for the domain and range.  The graph of $f$ is just $f,$ since $f$ is a set of ordered pairs.

Comment: One very common and useful notation is arrow notation: $$f : A \to B$$ means that $f$ is a function with domain $A$ and codomain $B$. I cannot think of any common notation for the graph $G$ itself, perhaps because it is quite rarely needed for most applications of the function concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Xander and @saulspatz mentioned above, it appears the applicable notations are:

$dom(f) = D(f) = Dmn(f)$

and

$ran(f) = R(f) = Rng(f)$